# Register a windows service through java code

Tags: java, jar, windows-services

How can I register a Windows service through a java code.I looked at Java service wrapper,winrun4j but actually I don't want to use any third party software or do any part of it manually.The service is already available,so what I want to do is register it as a windows service through a java code

Comment: Have you thought about writing a batch script and invoking it from Java?

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch file with the following command and gives call to this batch from your java program

You can use sc.exe:

```
sc create newservice binpath= "<path_to_the_executable>"
```

(must have quotation marks around the actual `exe` path.

More info is available [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192).

Comment: Thanks for your idea.I'll try itout.The other thing i want is that service should start when the computer starts up

Comment: Once the service willl be created, it will be registered and started automatically when your machine starts

Comment: If it solves your query, kindly accept it as the right answer.